# Remove None values or empty values from arrays of dictionaries in python

Tags: python-3.x

original

```
[{'l1Key': 'L1_SHARE', 'l2Key': None}, {'l1Key': 'L1_BROWSE_SOURCE', 'l2Key': None}, {'l1Key': 'L1_BLOCK_SOURCE', 'l2Key': None}, {'l1Key': 'L1_HIDE_NEWS', 'l2Key': None}, {'l1Key': 'NA', 'l2Key': 'HTML_2'}, {'l1Key': 'L1_SHOW_LESS', 'l2Key': 'HTML_2'}, {'l1Key': 'L1_SHOW_MORE', 'l2Key': None}]
```

expected answer

```
[{'l1Key': 'L1_SHARE'}, {'l1Key': 'L1_BROWSE_SOURCE'}, {'l1Key': 'L1_BLOCK_SOURCE', }, {'l1Key': 'L1_HIDE_NEWS'}, {'l1Key': 'NA', 'l2Key': 'HTML_2'}, {'l1Key': 'L1_SHOW_LESS', 'l2Key': 'HTML_2'}, {'l1Key': 'L1_SHOW_MORE'}]
```

i have tried with few codes but i am not getting as expected

```
[d for d in arr if all(d.values())]
[{'l1Key': 'NA', 'l2Key': 'HTML_2'}, {'l1Key': 'L1_SHOW_LESS', 'l2Key': 'HTML_2'}] //wrong as other key value pairs are all deleted if one of the keys is none or null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner using list comprehension :

```
original = [{'l1Key': 'L1_SHARE', 'l2Key': None}, {'l1Key': 'L1_BROWSE_SOURCE', 'l2Key': None}, {'l1Key': 'L1_BLOCK_SOURCE', 'l2Key': None}, {'l1Key': 'L1_HIDE_NEWS', 'l2Key': None}, {'l1Key': 'NA', 'l2Key': 'HTML_2'}, {'l1Key': 'L1_SHOW_LESS', 'l2Key': 'HTML_2'}, {'l1Key': 'L1_SHOW_MORE', 'l2Key': None}]
expected = [{k: v for (k, v) in i.items() if v not in [None, '']} for i in original]
```

gives

```
[{'l1Key': 'L1_SHARE'}, {'l1Key': 'L1_BROWSE_SOURCE'}, {'l1Key': 'L1_BLOCK_SOURCE'}, {'l1Key': 'L1_HIDE_NEWS'}, {'l1Key': 'NA', 'l2Key': 'HTML_2'}, {'l1Key': 'L1_SHOW_LESS', 'l2Key': 'HTML_2'}, {'l1Key': 'L1_SHOW_MORE'}]
```

Checking membership like `v not in [...]` gives you flexibility to filter with more options.

Comment: @vinaykn Please accept this answer (or any other) if it solved your problem

Answer (score 2):

```
d = [{'l1Key': 'L1_SHARE', 'l2Key': None}, {'l1Key': 'L1_BROWSE_SOURCE', 'l2Key': None}, {'l1Key': 'L1_BLOCK_SOURCE', 'l2Key': None}, {'l1Key': 'L1_HIDE_NEWS', 'l2Key': None}, {'l1Key': 'NA', 'l2Key': 'HTML_2'}, {'l1Key': 'L1_SHOW_LESS', 'l2Key': 'HTML_2'}, {'l1Key': 'L1_SHOW_MORE', 'l2Key': None}]
clean_d = []
for dict in d:
  clean_d.append({k: v for k, v in dict.items() if v is not None})
```

Answer (score 1):

`[d for d in arr if all(d.values())]`

In this line, you are selecting only those dictionaries which have all values that evaluate to a truthy. So you are missing the whole dictionary even if one value is `None` in your output.

You can delete the keys in place as follows without creating new dicts.

```
for curr in d:
    to_delete = [k for k, v in curr.items() if not v]
    for k in  to_delete:
       del curr[k]
```